# Newline missing when pressing Enter between open/close html tags in React files when tags have attributes

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I use vs code as an IDE. When I write in HTML file and hit enter after writing my tags it creates a line between tags but in JSX after hitting enter it does not create a new line between open/close tags
[image]

Comment: After hitting Enter, If you do CTRL+S what happens ?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Check you extensions... Is prettier there

Comment: yeah I have prettier, but in html it happens automatically without any extention

Comment: Nothing happens automatically my friend... There is a settings.json file and all settings are there :)

Comment: so, how can I make my js file act like HTML?

Comment: Before we could figure this out... Just tell me one thing.. In JSX are you unable to go to the newline ?

Comment: I can do it, but I want it to be like HTML when I hit enter it automatically opens new line

Comment: OK  Dear... I got it now. You mean you want to have a closing tag automatically as you write opening tag and do enter !!!  Suppose you write <div> and give an enter there should appear a closing div line </div> ... Am I right?

Comment: No, When I write <div> it automatically return <div></div> and when I hit enter it return the code in the picture but I want to have a line between tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226568/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-murad-petrosyan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following code into your `settings.json` file in VSCode:

```
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
```

And that will enable `emmet` in your  JSX.

You may also require to add the following two settings if not already enabled in the same `settings.json` file.

```
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

That should pretty much do it :)

Comment: Can you share your settings.json()

Comment: I dont know how to open a chat, pls open chat where I can send you the code

Comment: Bro thank u for your help. but I reinstalled vs code and all works))

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling **Babel ES6/ES7** extension if you have it installed. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you! this worked, I was going crazy